# how to post the code to some host

Tags: shared-hosting

how to post my web application and also the source code to a host..i want every one can see my project..i'm just know how to post an image..how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share your project using code.google.com  [click here](http://code.google.com/hosting/) where you can put all your code so that other peoples can also see your project.There is another option also that is GitHub you can also use   that but it is having limited space.One thing which very important that is before committing  your source code prepare proper documentation for your project because if documentations are not proper then it is of no use for other even if you written best quality code.